# Different output from uptime command

Tags: linux, uptime

When I use the uptime command on my linux vb, it shows its output like this before it has been on for longer than 1 hour;

13:45:25 **up 40 min**,  3 users,  load average: 0.41, 0.37, 0.27

But after the first hour of on-time, it displays it like this;

13:45:25 **up 01:40**,  3 users,  load average: 0.41, 0.37, 0.27

So it changes the human readable(?) up 40 minutes to the digital of up 01:40. What I want from my new uptime command is that it always gives the uptime in digital clock, so even when the pc has been on for 1 minute, it shows it like this;
13:45:25 **up 00:01**,  3 users,  load average: 0.41, 0.37, 0.27

Comment: Welcome to Unix.SE! What’s your question? Are you having trouble writing “your new `uptime` command”?

Comment: this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275907/on-linux-when-does-uptime-start-counting-from/275921#275921 might be useful

Comment: `/proc/uptime` has number of seconds the system has been up for. You may do with it whatever pleases you.

Comment: after somme days, uptimes will reply `14:13:42 up 128 days,  9:50,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00` how should it behave ? (note that after a year you still get uptime in days).

Comment: Yes I know, i was just wondering if somewhere in system files or somethign there would be a file with the exact time, so even if it had been on for a year it would still show it like 4523:23 < 4523 hours and 23 minutes